# How to use a variable in a string in Google Sheets Script Editor?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, string-concatenation, google-apps-script-editor

I'm a newbie to Script Editor, so I need some help.

```
function makeitright(){
var app1 = SpreadsheetApp;
var ss1 = app1.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var cred = ss1.getSheetByName("Crédito");
var lastrow = cred.getLastRow(); 

var formmod = 'ISBLANK('"H"+(lastrow+1)')'')';
```

I'm trying to write a formula to a single cell. But this formula will always change with a new added row. So I need the formula to work with the variable that gets the lastrow + 1.

Any ideas in how this could be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
'ISBLANK('"H"+(lastrow+1)')'')';
```

by

```
 'ISBLANK(H' + ( lastrow + 1 ) + ')';
```

To learn more read about how string concatenation works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way would be to use JavaScript [Template Literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
`ISBLANK(H${lastrow + 1})`;
```